# placing existing div over an existing div and then switching between them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Consider the following HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="div1" onclick="toggleDivs();">
        div1 content
    </div>
    <div id="div2" onclick="toggleDivs();" style="visibility:hidden">
        div2 content
    </div>
</body>
```

What I want is that when the user clicks on the currently visible div, the other div will become visible and the current div will become hidden.

I tried using `jquery.toggle()` and `jquery.css("visibility":"hidden/visible")` but none of those techniques worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`toggle`*<sup>[[API Ref]](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)</sup>* will work, but it operates on the `display` CSS attribute, not `visibility`. Just use `display` instead:

```
<div id="div1" onclick="toggleDivs();">
    div1 content
</div>
<div id="div2" onclick="toggleDivs();" style="display: none;">
    div2 content
</div>​
```

And the script:

```
function toggleDivs() {
    $('#div1, #div2').toggle();
}​
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/LrVUM/).

---

### Addendum:

I don't care for this solution compared to the previous one as much, but if, as per the OP's comment below, you wanted to accomplish this task using the `z-index`, you could do it like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/MkdLE/):

#### HTML:

```
<div id="div1" class="cycle">
    div1 content
</div>
<div id="div2" class="cycle">
    div2 content
</div>
```

#### CSS:

```
.cycle {
    position: absolute; /* The important thing is that the element 
                           is taken out of the document flow */
    background: #fff;
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    border: solid 1px #000;
}​
```

#### JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
   var cycleClick = function(e) {
        var $cycle = $('.cycle');
        $cycle.each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            var newZIndex = ($this.css('z-index') + 1) % $cycle.length;
            $this.css('z-index', newZIndex);
        });
        return false;
    };

    $('.cycle').click(cycleClick).each(function(idx) {
        $(this).css('z-index', idx);
    });​
});
```

Comment: can you give me an example using z-index?

Comment: Why do you need an example using z-index? Just curious.

Comment: because i know it can be done using z-index, and was wondering about the implementation differences on the css side..

Comment: See my addendum. A z-index solution requires more scripting and more styling, but you're right that it can be done.

Comment: I posted a much simpler z-index solution.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a jsfiddle that works:

http://jsfiddle.net/g5chb/1/

Amended code below:

```
<body>
    <div id="div1" >
         div1 content
    </div>
    <div id="div2" style="display:none">
         div2 content
    </div>
</body>​
```

and the relevant jQuery:

```
$("div").click(function(){
  $("#div1").toggle();   
  $("#div2").toggle();                    
});
```

Comment: It can be done in one line as well: `$("#div1,#div2").toggle();`

Answer (score 1):

A much simpler `z-index` solution is to just subtract 1 from the visible z-index.  You just need to put the div's on the page in reverse order.

```
$('.cycle').click(function() {
    $(this).css('z-index', $(this).css('z-index')-1);
});
​
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/jr7tR/3/

Comment: Please note the z-index solutions require a background to make sure the divs below aren't visible.